# React (TypeScript) のHookでFunctionComponentをCurry化しようとするとエラーになります

Tags: reactjs, typescript

ボタンの種類を渡す関数と、通常のHookのFunctionComponentの関数をカリー化しようとしたのですが、VSCodeのLintから以下のエラーメッセージが表示されます。

エラーメッセージ

```
(type: string) => (props: Props) => JSX.Element' を型 'FC<Props>' に割り当てることはできません。
  パラメーター 'type' および 'props' は型に互換性がありません。
    型 'PropsWithChildren<Props>' を型 'string' に割り当てることはできません。ts(2322)
index.tsx(15, 28): この式を呼び出すことを意図していましたか?
```

戻り値の型がFunctionComponentの定義に一致していないのは分かるのですが、どう直せば良いのか分からず困っています。

ソース

```
type Props = {
  type?: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
  children: ReactNode;
};

const ButtonA: FC<Props> = (type: string) => (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color={type} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こうですね

```
type Props = {
  type?: string;
  onClick?: () => void;
  children: ReactNode;
};

const ButtonA = (type: string): FC<Props> => (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color={type} onClick={props.onClick}>
      {props.children}
    </Button>
  );
};
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
書いてみると、なるほど納得しました。
この記述で問題なく実行でき、解決しました。